# Can React SDK used in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sdk, libraries

This sounds like a trivial question but I can't seem to find a definite answer from google.

I have read up articles about SDK and Library. I have basic understand of both.Based on my reading, I sum up SDK and Library as following:

Library:

```
Library is a chunk of codes that allows devs to perform certain action for specific task.
```

SDK:

```
While SDK is an interface, usually functions that allows the devs to interact with the library. It can also be groups of libraries for certain task
```

For library, from my experience, it is not cross JS-library,. For instance, an react library may not be used in pure javascipt library.

However, since SDK is more like an interface, does it mean the SDK is cross JS-library?

That means, if I implemented a React SDK, can it be used in pure javascript? and vise versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possible, yes. You can just import the libraries from some CDN as use them:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

However, this really isn't recommended as you won't get to use a lot of the great features that React has that would you get when using a build system (i.e. Webpack) and transpiler (i.e. Babel). For example:

You wouldn't be able to use JSX syntax so:

```
return (
    <h1>Greetings, {this.props.name}!</h1>
);
```

would become:

```
return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Greetings, ' + this.props.name + '!');
```

And you also wouldn't be able to make use of the ES6 goodies like arrow functions, promises, etc which are used extensively in most React projects.

Answer (score 0):

I dont recommend not using JSX preprocessor, but if you must write plain JS, folow this

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

There is also a react-pug implemention (pug is used in express to write nicer html with variables)
https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug